# Error: undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass when I updating my user information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

why not update user information, when I update user information showing this error:

> undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

What's wrong my code, show below:

controller:

```
def edit
  @users= User.find(params[:user_id])
end

def update
 #@users= User.find(params[:user_id])
 if @users.update_attributes(user_params)
  flash[:notice] = "User updated"
  render 'edit'
 else
  render 'edit'
 end
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:users).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :father_name, :mother_name )
end
```

Form:

```
<%= form_for :users, url: edit_path(@users), action: :update, method: :post  do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
   <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
   <%= f.text_field :father_name %>
   <%= f.text_field :mother_name %>

   <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
```

Routes:

```
 get  'edit'   => 'users#edit'
 post  'edit'   => 'users#update'
```

Model:

```
before_save { email.downcase! }

validates :first_name, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
validates :last_name, :presence => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, format: { with: /\A[^@\s]+@([^@.\s]+\.)+[^@.\s]+\z/ }

has_secure_password
#validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add your password field on your update form section & **uncomment** this line:

`#@users= User.find(params[:user_id])`.

Nicely represent on this site: [Update](http://def%20update%20%20%20%20%20@jobseekers%20=%20Jobseeker.find(params[:jobseeker_id])%20%20%20%20%20#@jobseekers%20=%20Jobseeker.update_attributes(params[:jobseekers])%20%20%20%20%20%20%20params.permit!%20%20%20%20%20if%20@jobseekers%20%20%20%20%20%20%20@jobseekers.update_attributes(params[:jobseekers])%20%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20Handle%20a%20successful%20update.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20flash[:notice]%20=%20%22Your%20profile%20updated%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20render%20'uploadResume'%20%20%20%20%20else%20%20%20%20%20%20%20render%20'uploadResume'%20%20%20%20%20end%20%20%20end)

You see this

Hope will help you

Comment: Please try to use variable name in singular for single record - '@user'. 
'@users' - will represent array of users, will give confusion for others to see the code

Answer (score 0):

> undefined method `update_attributes' for nil:NilClass

You need to ***uncomment*** the line `#@users= User.find(params[:user_id])` in `update` action.

```
def update
  @users= User.find(params[:user_id])
  if @users.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:notice] = "User updated"
    render 'edit'
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Comment: If **uncomment** this line not showing error but attribute not update

Comment: @try You need to change `method: :post` to `method: :put` in `form_for`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users, only: [:edit, :update] #-> url.com/users/:id/edit

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @user = User.find params[:id]
   end

   def update
      @user = User.find params[:id] #-> this is where your error occurs
      @user.update user_params
   end

   private

   def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :father_name, :mother_name)
   end
end

#app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <% fields = @user.attributes - %i(id created_at updated_at) %>
   <% fields.each do |field| %>
      <%= f.text_field field %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

--

Calling `update_attributes` on `@users` requires `@users` to be an instance of a class. In your case, it hasn't been invoked, which leads to the `NilClass` error.

Since Ruby is an object orientated language, it treats every piece of data as an *object*, even undeclared ones. When you see `undefined method for NilClass` errors, it basically means you're trying to manipulate a non-existent variable.